snmpwalk print OID + MIB name side by side on all output
I want to be able to print out all OID and MIB names side by side.
This will print oids
snmpwalk -v2c -c public 10.10.10.10

This will print mibs
snmpwalk -v2c -c public -m ALL 10.10.10.10

How can I show te OID + the MIB name on the same line?
I found this seems to work, but is there an easier way?
snmpwalk -v2c -c public 10.10.10.10 > oids
snmpwalk -v2c -c public -m ALL 10.10.10.10 > mibs
paste pan-oids pan-mibs > oid-mibs


If you are restricted to use only shell scripts and Net-SNMP command line tools, then that's the best you can get. Programming with Python and PySNMP might give you similar results, but might not be what you asked for.
